# AjaxStart and AjaxStop Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use ajaxStart and ajaxStop to show a loading gif.
It was working fine until i added this piece of code:

```
$(function(){  
$('.link a').live('click', function(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();


    $('#main').load($(this).attr('href'));


  return false;
});
});
```

This is my ajaxStart/Stop code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#loading").show();
 }).ajaxStop(function(){
    $("#loading").hide();
 });
```

Please help :)

**EDIT**: The code I added which is causing the problem, was added to enable links of a page within a div to load the links in the div itself when clicked, instead of loading the entire window. AjaxStart and AjaxStop works fine when the page is newly loaded, but once I click a link in the div (which loads a page), the AjaxStart does not fire.

The code for the links (which are in the page inside a div):

```
 echo "<span class = 'link'><a href='feed.php?".$new_query_string ."' id='page_a_link'     name='page_a_link' >$i</a></span>";

 echo "<span class = 'link'><a id='page_a_link' name='page_a_link' href='feed.php?".$new_query_string ."' >< Pre</a></span>";

 echo "<span class = 'link'><a href='feed.php?".$new_query_string ."' id='page_a_link' name='page_a_link' >Next</a></span>";
```

These are for pagination. I just took the link part out of the PHP code.

Comment: i think it's because of the ev.stopPropogation(); try removing that.

Comment: In what way is the new code broken?

Comment: Tried removing ev.stopPropogation(). Did not make a difference.

Comment: Added more details in the EDIT

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you reload the page, the content and therefore the pagination links, are replaced and you lose the old bind click events

Try this code:

```
$(function(){  


  function bindPagination() {
    $('span.link a').on('click', function(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       // ev.stopPropagation();

       $('#main').load($(this).attr('href'), function(){
          //callback function fired when page loaded
          //now rebind click event
          bindPagination(); 
       });

       return false;
    });   
  }

});
```

and try to change the "loader" in this way:

```
$('#loader')
  .bind("ajaxSend", function() {
    $(this).show(); 
        })
  .bind("ajaxComplete", function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: .link and a.link does not work. I have posted the HTML code you requested for. Thanks!

Comment: Still the same issue. Another thing I did not mention, the page loading works. The page loads, just that the ajaxStart doesn't execute. Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: It's still the same mate. The issue is still there

Comment: @saravanen-marimuthu answer re-edited (try to remove the ev.stopPropagation() and change the loader bind. A question: the "loader" div is outside the "main" div?

Comment: Yes it is outside the main div